# How to hide jQuery validator error message for a particular field by using $("div.error").hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I want to hide a jQuery validator error message for a specific field. My current form is

```
<input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" class="required">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="required">
```

I'm using `$("div.error").hide();` to hide jQuery error messages. The code hides all of the error messages. but I want to hide only error message of password field.

Can we use `$("div.error #password").hide();`?

Comment: Do you want to hide the error message for password field or the password field itself on error ? Please be clearer.

Comment: @AnudeepRentala ⇒ Sorry for my mistake explanation! I want to hide only error message of password field.

Comment: **Quote**:  *"Can we use `$("div.error #password").hide();`"* ~ Can't you simply try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using JQuery validate
Your error message is displayed in a label with the for attribute being equal to the control with error. 
So,

`$('label[for="password"]').hide()` would work

Comment: ⇒yes, your code is could work! Now, I could hide error message by using your code, but I have background color for error message. I want to also hide background color of specific error message.Thank you for your advice!